# How to find previous N siblings of an element

Tags: java, html, xpath, html-parsing, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to parse HTML pae in java, i want to get all the tables from a page and then find 5 previous siblings for every tables.
This is how I am parsing tables in page :

```
List<HtmlTable> tables = (List<HtmlTable>) page.getByXPath("//table");              
         if(tables!=null && tables.size()>0) {
                  for(int k=tables.size()-1; k>=0; k--) {
                     for (HtmlTableRow row : tables.get(k).getRows()) {
                         List<HtmlTableCell> tds = row.getCells();
                                                                      }
                                                        }
                                            }
```

So if a table is like this :

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div></div>
<table>
.
.
</table>
```

I need to get `<div>` and two `<p>` elements.

JSoup seem to have a method for sibling http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#previousElementSibling%28%29 , not able to find any thing like this in HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of functions available in `HtmlUnit` too. Check The followings from the online `HtmlUnit` documentation:

1. [getPrentNode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html?is-external=true#getParentNode%28%29)
2. [getChildElements()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement.html#getChildElements%28%29)
3. [getPreviousSibling()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getPreviousSibling%28%29) or [getPreviousElementSibling()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement.html#getPreviousElementSibling%28%29)

Try using this, to get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a more appropriate `XPath` expression:

```
//table/preceding-sibling::*[position()<=3]
```

Given

```
<html> 
  <p/>  
  <p/>  
  <div/>  
  <table> 
    <tr>
      <td>sdf</td>
    </tr> 
  </table> 
</html>
```

This will return:

```
  <p/>
  <p/>
  <div/>
```

Test it [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/863e535b-1459-487d-ad55-7b818311a0ec).

Then you just iterate over the results in the simplest way.